# Grep for string, but within bounds

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I've been trying to filter a file which has several repetitions of lines which looks as follows:

```
('hello
My name is
jamie
blabla
xyz>>)
('hello
My name is
kat
blabla
blablabla
x2>>)
('hello
My name is
oliver
xv>>)
```

I am trying to merge all lines between (' and >>) into a single line and then grep for a pattern.

```
awk '/('hello/{if (NR!=1)print "";next}{print $0}END{print "";}'
```

seems to produce slightly weird results, by adding an extra blank line between these chunks of lines, however not sure if I can combine them somehow.

By merging lines, I am expecting an output as follows:

```
('hello My name is jamie blabla xyz>>)
('hello My name is kat blabla blablabla x2>>)
('hello My name is oliver xv>>)
```

from which I can grep for any value.

Thanks.

Comment: Show expected output

Comment: So… you don't want to grep for anything. You just want to join all lines between open and close parens?

Comment: @kojiro I think they want to search for `hello`, but all the example blocks have it in them...

Comment: @123 so perhaps join all lines between open and close parens, then grep for 'hello' :)

Comment: @kojiro What my answer does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to merge the lines then grep - just use awk and do it both in one concise script. With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -F'\n' 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=")\n"} /hello/{$1=$1;print}' file
('hello My name is jamie blabla xyz>>)
('hello My name is kat blabla blablabla x2>>)
('hello My name is oliver xv>>)

$ awk -F'\n' 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=")\n"} /jamie/{$1=$1;print}' file
('hello My name is jamie blabla xyz>>)
```

Comment: Awk on OS X outputs a final `)` for some reason.

Comment: @Ed M.,anubhava , it´s great to follow and studying your answers :) thanks for your sharing your expertise guys

Comment: On my actual data, two lines seem to get bunched together. Is there a quick way to add a line break after every match?

Comment: @jamie: You can use: `awk 'BEGIN{RS=")\n"; ORS=")\n\n"} {$1=$1} 1' file`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a limit on the maximum length of lines that I can have in this case? I can observer several lines being truncated as well.

Comment: @jamie - don't try to put band-aids on it. If you have input data that this doesn't work perfectly for then there's something about that input data that's different from what you posted. Investigate, identify the difference(s), and edit your question to show the new data so we can help you. Usually any input data issues are caused by files having been created on Windows and so having spurious control-Ms in them. Use `cat -v file` to see them and if present `dos2unix` or similar to remove them. No, there is no limit.

Comment: @kojiro you aren't using GNU awk. Get it as you are missing a LOT of extremely useful functionality.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. Apparently seems to be some issue with my terminal. If I write to a file and read from an editor, it seems to work okay...

Comment: @anubhava we only need the `-F'\n'` if the OP wants to test for specific lines matching a regexp or string, e.g. `...$3=="jamie"...` to only match `jamie` in the 3rd field/line of every record.

Comment: @jamie it's almost certainly the control-Ms I mentioned. Your terminal is obeying their instruction to jump back to the start of the line but your editor is interpreting it as a DOS-format file and effectively ignoring them. Try what I suggested with `cat -v file` and `dos2unix` (or `sed 's/\r$//'`).

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

Sedtest.sed

```
/('/{:1;N;/>>)/!b1;/hello/{s/\n/ /gp}};d
```

or expanded

```
/('/{
#Search for start string
   :1
#Label to loop to
   N
#Get next line
   />>)/!b1
#Break to label until end pattern is matched
   /hello/{
#When that loops done search for hello in block
   s/\n/ /gp
#Change newlines to space and print
   }
}
d
#Delete everything ever
```

file

```
('hello
My name is
jamie
blabla
xyz>>)
('hello
My name is
kat
blabla
blablabla
x2>>)
('hello
My name is
oliver
xv>>)
```

Execute as

```
sed -f Sedtest file
```

Produces

```
('hello My name is jamie blabla xyz>>)
('hello My name is kat blabla blablabla x2>>)
('hello My name is oliver xv>>)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tr $'\n' ' ' < infile | grep -o "('hello[^(]*)"
('hello My name is jamie blabla xyz>>)
('hello My name is kat blabla blablabla x2>>)
('hello My name is oliver xv>>)
```

`tr` replaces all newlines with spaces, the grep extracts all expressions in parentheses that start with `'hello`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`, I would do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ")\n";

while  ( <DATA> ) { 
    s/\n(?!$)/ /g;
    print if /hello/;
}

__DATA__
('hello
My name is
jamie
blabla
xyz>>)
('hello
My name is
kat
blabla
blablabla
x2>>)
('hello
My name is
oliver
xv>>)
```

This explicitly removes linefeeds, to match your desired result. However you don't actually need to:

```
while  ( <DATA> ) { 
    print if /jamie/;
}
```

Works just fine, and gives:

```
('hello
My name is
jamie
blabla
xyz>>)
```

That's written out long hand for clarity - you can reduce to a one liner:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/=')'} print if m/jamie/' filename
```

(This also accepts piped information).